# Cascading Dropdown with MVC VS2010 AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm tryhing to create a Ajax driven cascading dropdown list. The examples I found uses a web service however, using VS2010 web service does not come with. Instead I thought I would use MVC. I've followed another tutorial which showed how to set up a MVC service, but my iteration doesn't work. As I have not done a web server or a MVC service before I thought it shouldn't be so tough, but I've ran aground. Can someone point out what I've done wrong? I get this error "Compiler Error Message: CS0524: 'Locations': interfaces cannot declare types"

Please see my code bellow. Thanks. Risho

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILocations
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Locations> GetLocations(int ident);

    [DataContract] 
    public class Locations   <<- ERROR *******************************
    {
       int ident = 0;
       string description = string.Empty;

       [DataMember]
       public int Ident
       {
           get { return ident; }
           set { ident = value; }
       }

       [DataMember]
       public string Description
       {
           get { return description; }
           set { description = value; }
       }
    }
}


public class Locations : ILocations
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    string connString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbLocations"].ToString();

List<ILocations.Locations>GetLocations(int ident)
{
        cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(connString);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_Location_Get_Children";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pintParentIdent", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@pintParentIdent"].Value = ident;

        List<ILocations.Locations> _location = new List<ILocations.Locations>();

        try
        {
           SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
           DataTable dtLocations = new DataTable();
           da.Fill(dtLocations);

           if (dtLocations.Rows.Count > 0)
           {
                for (int i = 0; i < dtLocations.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    ILocations.Locations _locInfo = new ILocations.Locations();
                    _locInfo.Ident = Convert.ToInt32(dtLocations.Rows[i]["ident"]);
                    _locInfo.Description = dtLocations.Rows[i]["description"].ToString();

                   _location.Add(_locInfo);
                }
            }
            return _location;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            throw;
        }
    }
 }


<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="cddLocations" runat="server"
         TargetControlID="ddlLocationDetail"
         Category="description"
         PromptText="Select Location"
         LoadingText="Loading..."
         ServicePath="~/App_Code/ILocations.cs"
         ServiceMethod=""
         ParentControlID="ddlRoomLocation"
         SelectedValue="ident" />
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlRoomLocation" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
             DataTextField="description" DataValueField="ident"
             width="246px" CssClass="AssetMngnt-smallFont" AutoPostBack="true" 
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRoomLocation_OnSelectedIndexChanged" >
            <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Selected="True">-- Select a Location --      </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="-2">-- All Printers --</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:DropDownList Visible="false" runat="server" ID="ddlLocationDetail" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
             DataTextField="description" DataValueField="ident"
             width="246px" CssClass="AssetMngnt-smallFont" AutoPostBack="true" 
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLocationDetail_OnSelectedIndexChanged" >
            <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Selected="True">-- Select a Detail --</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: your code sample uses DropDownList control, which is a web form control. There is no such controls in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: That is correct, I'm building a website. Apperantly in VS2010 web serive has been replaced with MVC service to work with the Ajax cascading dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Take the class "Locations" declaration out of the interface "ILocations" declaration. Those cannot be nested.